# How to write the loop in java for the output shown below?

Tags: java, loops

I need help to write java code that will display the output as the picture shown

[image]

Comment: you wana code for this, do some hardware

Comment: What do you need help with? Surely you've already tried something.

Comment: @Joni i need the java code on how to get the output shown in above.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried so far. We are not here to do your homework at your place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        if(j == i * 2 + 1) {     
            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

First `for`-loop is for each row. (This is why this loop ends with `System.out.println()` to skip to the next row.)
The inner `for`-loop is for the output each row should print. Here you find the `if(j == i * 2 + 1)` statement. If j is equal to i * 2 + 1, it should print the " - ". (Check it yourself for each value of i and j.).

Comment: that is the answer!! thanks. but what if need to calculate the number of row ?

Comment: i + 1 is each row number. (It starts with 0 and ends with 5.)

Comment: what i mean is how to modify the code so it can have a configurable number of stars " * " and automatically calculate the corresponding number of rows?

Comment: Declare variables to set this and add them to the loop condition statement.

Something like:

   `int numberOfStars = 20`
   `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStars / 2; i++) {`
        `for(int j = 0; j <= numberOfStars; j++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
public class PatternTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                System.out.print("-");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}}
```

Comment: @Anita Ramaiah thanks though. but what if it need to have configurable number of the star and calculate the number of rows? any idea?

Comment: you can have the dynamic number instead of 5(that I have placed)

Answer (score 0):

Never ever post your homework problems here. Try something and post what you tried. You just don't request code for some problem.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j<13; j++)
           {
              if(2*i+1 == j)
                  System.out.print(" - ");
              else
                  System.out.print("*");
           }
           System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```